# find a vector function that represents the curve of intersection of the two surfaces

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

The cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the plane $z=1+y$

I parameterized the plane and put it into vector form:

$t=1+y \to y=t-1$

$z= 1+t-1 \to z = t$

$y= t-1$, $z=t$

Since I'm finding the intersection, I can just plug the parameters from the plane into the cone and get x:

$t = \sqrt{x^2+(t-1)^2} \to t^2 = x^2 + t^2 - 2t +1 \to x^2 = -2t+1 \to x = \sqrt{-2t+1}$

for the vector equation I have:
$\Big(\sqrt{-2t+1}i+t-1j+tk\Big)$

Comment: $$t = \sqrt{x^{2} + (t-1)^{2}} \iff t^{2} = x^{2} + t^{2} - 2t + 1 \iff x^{2} = 2t - 1$$

Comment: That's not a parameterization of the plane- a plane is two dimensional so requires two parameters.  Since the equation of the plane does not mention 'x', it is independent of y and z so a parameterization would be x= s, y= t- 1, z= t.  A parameterization for the cone would be x= p cos(q), y= p sin(q), z= p.  At a point where they intersect we must have x= s= p cos(q), y= t- 1= p sin(q), z= t= p.  So s= t cos(q) and t-  1= t sin(q). Then s^2+ (t-1)^2= s^2+ t^2- 2t+ 1= t^2.  s^2= 2t- 1 so x= sqrt(2t- 1), y= t- 1, z= t is the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it this way.

$1+y = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
1+2y + y^2 = x^2+ y^2\\
1+2y = x^2\\
y = \frac 12 x^2 - \frac 12$

now I would say: 
$x = t\\
y = \frac 12 t^2 - \frac 12\\
z = \frac 12 t^2 + \frac 12$

Comment: Thats how the book did it. Okay makes sense